# writing let in vb 2013

Tags: vb.net, let

I am trying to write `Let` in VB and it won't let me do it, it keeps erasing itself. Do I need to download a package or something?

For example:

```
    If Not currentDirectory = "" Then
        Dim lines() As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(currentDirectory)


        Dim data = From line In lines


        Let  nam = line.Split(","c)(0)
        Let  num = line.Split(","c)(1)
        Order By nam Ascending 

        Select nam, num

        DataGridView1.DataSource = data.ToList

        DataGridView1.CurrentCell = Nothing

        DataGridView1.Columns("nam").HeaderText = "Name"

        DataGridView1.Columns("num").HeaderText = "Phone Number"


    End If
```

It will not let me type "Let"

Comment: It is unnecessary to type `let`. It should work without it either

Comment: in many cases you can use `Dim` where you once used `Let`: `Dim nam = line.Split(","c)(0)`.  Also, it is never too late to start accepting answers (clicking the checkmark) on past answers which have helped you.

Comment: Ok, I tried that first but now it says Line statements are no longer supported. File I/O functionality is available as Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileSystem.LineInput and graphics functionality is available as System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawLine.

Comment: how do I accept answers?

Comment: You can click the check mark next to their answer, and/or vote up by clicking the up arrow right above it.  See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Click the checkmark outline next to those that helped the most or fixed your problem. see [Tour]

Comment: But there are no answers for this question. Only comments.

Answer (score 2):

You murdered a Linq query comprehension.  You need to type it **without** using empty lines between the query parts, the text editor won't type you `Let` if you add an extra empty line.  Do keep in mind that line-endings are statement terminators in VB.NET

Properly typed, it should look like this:

```
    Dim data = From line In lines
               Let nam = line.Split(","c)(0)
               Let num = line.Split(","c)(1)
               Order By nam Ascending
               Select nam, num
```